# Manually importing project in eclipse does not work?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm not able to find out why does the manually importing any project even a very small app like "hello World" is not importing successfully.
I receive lots of compilation errors saying that `name` is not resolved.

Basically `name` could be anything,  it could be variable, it could be `package` or even class name, it can't be resolved by eclipse.
But when i made explicitly that project into eclipse - it works fine? please help me out?

Comment: This question can't be answered. First of all: use short sentences if you have trouble with the English language. Subject verb object; and surprise Interpunktation helps other people to understand your text. Then: we don't have a magic ball. We have no idea how the project you imported looks like; nor do we know what else you might have done. So; step back, and start describing clearly what you were doing.

Comment: I am explaining to you why you only got a downvote and 2 close requests so far. If that makes me a Nazi, well then you might find that this site is full of Nazis. And maybe, full of newbies that think other people will spend their free time to help; even when the newbies do not show any respect for the policies of this site.

Comment: @Jägermeister if it wasn't for points, people like you wouldn't be here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add new system library, this is like common where we get errors.

Comment: Sorry pal, but this is not an answer; you don't provide any real information. Which is fair; but then write up comments, not answers.

Comment: Thanks bro! I removed the JRE system library and then i added it again it works for me